# Symfony skip null value during serialization

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

Im trying to serialize an object and skipping null value this is the object i try to serialize:

```
{
  key1: null
  key2: null
  key3: {
     keyA: null
     keyB: 'value'
  }
  key4: 'value'
}
```

if i use the following method :

```php
$object = self::getInstance()->serialize($object, "json", ['skip_null_values' => true]);
```

the object is succesfully serialized but it only remove the null key of the first level and not the one from the `key3` object.

```
{
  key3: {
     keyA: null
     keyB: 'value'
  }
  key4: 'value'
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this using the Symfony Serializer Component ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AbstractObjectNormalizer::SKIP_NULL_VALUES` flag to skip null values when normalizing:

```
$json = $serializer->serialize(
    $user,
    JsonEncoder::FORMAT,
    [AbstractObjectNormalizer::SKIP_NULL_VALUES => true]
);
```

Source: https://lindevs.com/skip-null-values-during-serialization-in-symfony/

Answer (score -1):

You can consider JMSSerializerBundle instead of Symfony serializer

it's easy to use. You can serialize nulls as empty strings

```
$context = new SerializationContext();
$context->setSerializeNull(true);
$objectData = $serializer->serialize($object, 'json', $context);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the context to pass `setSerializeNull(true)`

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Context\Context;
```

in your function:

```
$data = ...
$view = $this->view($data, 200);

$context = new Context();
$context->setSerializeNull(true);
$view->setContext($context);

return $this->handleView($view);
```

Comment: OP use symfony/serializer, not JMS/serializer